# Variable object constructor

Tags: javascript, object

Consider the following simple object:

```
var foo = {
    constructor: function(){
        console.log("foo");
    },
    bar: function(){
        console.log("bar");
    }
}

//should return "foo\nbar"
foo.bar();
```

Is it possible to create a constructor for this variable object that would allow me to execute foo.bar() as well as foo.constructor() by just calling foo.bar()?

Comment: No, why would calling `foo.bar()` call that other function? You'd need to do `this.constructor()` inside of  `bar` to achieve the desired result. It's unclear why you call this "a constructor", since it doesn't construct anything.

Comment: What is your [actual problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)?

Answer (score 2):

```
var foo = {
    constructor: function(){
        console.log("foo");
    },
    bar: function(){
        this.constructor();
        console.log("bar");
    }
}

//should return "foo\nbar"
foo.bar();
```

Comment: I know this is a valid answer, but in my actual JS file I have 10 or so methods, and I don't want to put this.constructor() in each method.

Comment: @evan We would need to see the rest of your code then, as there may be a better way to structure your code.